# JS scroll page lag/stutter

Tags: javascript, scroll, requestanimationframe

Im trying to make smooth scrolling text. Speed must be consisten, so user can read it without "jumps". Also it should be able to change speed on user actions. But i cant achieve totally smooth behaviour. No matter what approach i try its always not perfect and stutters/lag/jump at least a little from time to time

I used setInterval method. And on slow speeds it work fine. But when i increase pixels step even on interval of 1ms it become not smooth and hard to read text.

I did research and found requestAnimationFrame method. Which works perfectly for me, except - it drop frames from time to time. And it make page freeze for a milliseconds, but its already noticable, and it become worse when it drops multiple frames in a short period of time.

The code im using right now:

```
    let start
    scroll_speed = 10
    direction = 1
    
    function scroll(timestamp) {
        if (!start) {
            start = timestamp
        }
    
        // 60hz
        if (timestamp - start >= 17) {
            console.log(timestamp - start)
        }
    
        start = timestamp
    
        window.scrollTo({
            top: window.scrollY + (scroll_speed * direction)
        })

        window.requestAnimationFrame(scroll)
    }
```

and when scroll lag, i get this in console:
33.459000000031665
32.88800000003539
33.3080000000773

I found this answer, and its nice visualisation of what happening
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46346441

[image]

Give me a hint, what can i do to fix it please.